# Can SMPS works as cellphone charger?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, charger, mobile

I tested for charging a mobile using SMPS, it charges the battery 10% percent in an hour. But when I connect the same mobile to the mobile charger it charges the battery 40% in an hour.

The SMPS input and output ratings are

**IN  100 - 240V AC
    0.23A, 50-60Hz
OUT  5V DC /2000mA.**

Charger input and output ratings are

**IN  100 - 240V AC
     0.35A, 50-60Hz
OUT  5V DC /2000mA.**

What is the reason for slow charging in SMPS..?

And Can I make fast charging using any additional circuits for SMPS?

Comment: Your mobile phone charger *is* an smps

Comment: Your phone does not recognize the power source and cuts back on the charge rate in the hope of preventing a catastrophic failure. It is a built in safety feature. 1. TO protect you, and 2. To protect them from the Samsung Galaxy 7 fiasco.

Comment: We need to create a reference question for _"Help, I can't build a phone charger"_-type questions. They all boil down to the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile phone chargers use mains voltage which is converted to 5V DC and then the USB socket is used to charge the phone. Inside the charger is an SMPS which converts the voltage to 5V. The reason your device will charge slower when using your home made device is because the manufacturers include resistor dividers on the D+ and D- pins in the charger to give a set voltage. These then tell the phone the type of charger being used and how much current it can draw from it. A good article is [HERE](https://learn.adafruit.com/minty-boost/icharging)
which explains quite nicely how different voltages on the D+ and D- pins can determine current draw.

It is all a safety thing to prevent an overcurrent situation. Basically, the phone won't recognise your charger as an authentic charging unit so will only draw a small amount of current from it as a safety precaution.

As for your question;

> Can I make fast charging using any additional circuits for SMPS?

Yes, you can, but you will most likely have to open up a faulty (authentic) charger and measure the D+ and D- pin voltages so you can get your resistor dividers correct. Even doing this will result in it only being able to 'fast charge' that particular model, as others will have different configurations (as I found when I designed a portable charger that charges my Samsung nicely but is slow with charging any iPhones after the iPhone 6s).

Comment: It's working normal fast after done voltage changes at D+ and D-. but only for Samsung, when it connects to other higher battery rating mobiles it takes a long time to charge. Can I avoid this slow charging for higher rated batteries like 3000mAh - 4000mAh .

Comment: It isn't the battery type that affects charging rate, it's the phone type. You would have to check the resistor configurations for each *phone* type if you wanted to get each of them working with a fast charge

Comment: okay, what is the basic voltage requirement circuit for traditional charging to all mobiles. I find that 0.3V at D+ and 0V or GND at D-  is this suitable for all and is it harmful to mobiles charging through this method?

Comment: There isn't a standard across all devices unfortunately. doing it your way may work for some mobiles, but not all. You would have to look into it a bit more

Answer (score 1):

1) The **phone** determines the charging rate, so not the power adapter.

2) The original power adapter uses signals (on the USB datalines) so that the phone **knows** it is the original power adapter which can deliver the required current.

3) the phone **cannot** detect that the SMPS **can** actually deliver 2A (since the SMPS does not provide the identification signals like the original power adapter does) so the phone plays it safe and draws a smaller current. Then charging takes longer.

It depends on the actual charger and phone model what will be needed to make the phone fast charge with a non-original adapter. For some (older) devices shorting the DATA+ and DATA- pins is enough. Others use more complex signals, like [QuickCharge](https://blog.oxplot.com/quickcharge/).

Answer (score 0):

When connected to a USB port, the portable device has no power to consume more than 100 mA. This is enough to conduct a digital negotiation, in which the portable device determines the port power requirements.

A typical SMPS power supply does not support a digital negotiation.

[Battery Charging v1.2 Spec and Adopters Agreement](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/BCv1.2_070312.zip) describe the charger requirements.

[There is](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/5801) also a brief overview.

You can use a USB charger adapter emulators.

> For example, the [MAX14630](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/MAX14630)/[MAX14632](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/MAX14632) are charger adapter
>   emulators that can be configured to automatically detect a USB
>   BC1.2-compliant device, Apple 1.0A device, Apple 2.1A device, or
>   Samsung®Galaxy Tablet 2A device.
>
> [image]